# Codeigniter db cache conflict with browser cache

Tags: codeigniter, browser-cache, database-caching

I'm using db cache in my codeigniter project and when I uploaded that application to the server there is a little conflict between db cache that I use and store on the server and browser cache that I use with htaccess file.

What's exactly the problem. When both caching methods are activated there are problems with properly displaying content, for example when I explore my site as a guest and then login to account it display on some pages(exactly on those pages that I explored as a guest) like I wouldn't be logged in, it change only when I refresh the website using f5 or click a refresh button in the browser.

So my question is how can I use both caching(db cache from ci and browser caching) without those problems with displaying correct content? Or maybe I should choose only 1 method to cache?

Kind Regards